# WriteableBitmapEx - merge two images in one

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, writeablebitmap

I want to merge two images into one. I read that I should use WriteableBitmapEx library and use blit method. Both of my images are Image type.

So, should I first convert Image type to WriteableBitmap ?
Like this:

```
var im1 = image1.ToImage().ToBitmap(); 
var im2 = image2.ToImage().ToBitmap();
```

And how can I use method blit now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use WriteableBitmapEx library to use the image merge functionality in your application [WriteableBitmapEx Library](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) has Blit Method.

Here is an example for the same see the following link

- [Image Blitting in Silverlight with WriteableBitmapEx](http://adamkinney.com/blog/2010/01/09/image-blitting-in-silverlight-with-writeablebitmapex/)

Hope it helps